# CUDA not working in 64 bit windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2008, cuda

I have cuda toolkit 4.0 installed in a 64 bit windows 7. I try building my cuda code,

```
#include<iostream>
#include"cuda_runtime.h"
#include"cuda.h"
__global__ void kernel(){
} 
int main(){
kernel<<<1,1>>>();
int c = 0;
cudaGetDeviceCount(&c);
cudaDeviceProp prop;
cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, 0);
std::cout<<"the name is"<<prop.name;
std::cout<<"Hello World!"<<c<<std::endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

but operation fails. Below is the build log:

Build Log      Rebuild started: Project: god, Configuration: Debug|Win32
Command Lines      Creating temporary file "c:\Users\t-sudhk\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\god\god\Debug\BAT0000482007500.bat" with contents
[
@echo off

echo "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.0\bin\nvcc.exe"    -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\"  --machine 32 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin"    -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /O2 /Zi   /MT  "  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.0\include" -maxrregcount=0  --compile -o "Debug/sample.cu.obj" sample.cu

"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.0\bin\nvcc.exe"    -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\"  --machine 32 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin"    -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /O2 /Zi   /MT  "  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.0\include" -maxrregcount=0  --compile -o "Debug/sample.cu.obj" "c:\Users\t-sudhk\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\god\god\sample.cu"

if errorlevel 1 goto VCReportError

goto VCEnd

:VCReportError

echo Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Compiling with CUDA Build Rule..."

exit 1

:VCEnd
]
Creating command line """c:\Users\t-sudhk\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\god\god\Debug\BAT0000482007500.bat"""
Creating temporary file "c:\Users\t-sudhk\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\god\god\Debug\RSP0000492007500.rsp" with contents
[
/OUT:"C:\Users\t-sudhk\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\god\Debug\god.exe" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.0\lib\x64" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"Debug\god.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\Users\t-sudhk\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\god\Debug\god.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 cudart.lib cuda.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib

".\Debug\sample.cu.obj"
]
Creating command line "link.exe @"c:\Users\t-sudhk\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\god\god\Debug\RSP0000492007500.rsp" /NOLOGO /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT"
 Output Window      Compiling with CUDA Build Rule...
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.0\bin\nvcc.exe"    -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\"  --machine 32 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin"    -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /O2 /Zi   /MT  "  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.0\include" -maxrregcount=0  --compile -o "Debug/sample.cu.obj" sample.cu 
sample.cu
sample.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cudaLaunch@4 referenced in function "enum cudaError **cdecl cudaLaunch(char *)" (??$cudaLaunch@D@@YA?AW4cudaError@@PAD@Z)
sample.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___cudaRegisterFunction@40 referenced in function "void __cdecl _*sti***_cudaRegisterAll_52_tmpxft_00001c68_00000000_8_sample_compute_10_cpp1_ii_b81a68a1(void)" (?**sti_**_cudaRegisterAll_52_tmpxft_00001c68_00000000_8_sample_compute_10_cpp1_ii_b81a68a1@@YAXXZ)
sample.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol **_cudaRegisterFatBinary@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl _*sti***_cudaRegisterAll_52_tmpxft_00001c68_00000000_8_sample_compute_10_cpp1_ii_b81a68a1(void)" (?**sti_**_cudaRegisterAll_52_tmpxft_00001c68_00000000_8_sample_compute_10_cpp1_ii_b81a68a1@@YAXXZ)
sample.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cudaGetDeviceProperties@8 referenced in function _main
sample.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cudaGetDeviceCount@4 referenced in function _main
sample.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cudaConfigureCall@32 referenced in function _main
C:\Users\t-sudhk\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\god\Debug\god.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals
 Results      Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\t-sudhk\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\god\god\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
god - 8 error(s), 0 warning(s)

I will be highly obliged if someone could help me. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you are not linking the cuda runtime library. I can't tell you how to fix that in visual studio, but that is the source of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Add cudart.lib to your additional libraries.  [See here for more info](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=103796).

To add the library, Go to

Project Properties / Configuration Properties / Linker / Input / Additional Dependencies

and add `cudart.lib`

**Update:** CUDA be default will only install native binaries.  You're on a 64bit system.  If you *must* compile a 32bit application, then you will probably need to download and install the 32bit CUDA Toolkit to get the 32bit binaries -- I thought they were including them by default, but I'm away from my Win7 box right now -- I'll check later & update.

The other option, **which I would strongly recommend**, would be to switch to building native, 64bit binaries.  To do so, you'll need to edit the `Configuration Management` and switch from Win32 to x64.

[image]

If you don't have an x64 option, you'll need to go into the third `Configuration Management` option and add a profile for x64.

The basic point is that since you're trying to link a 32 bit app, it ignores the 64bit binaries which you have installed.

Comment: Note it's pictured in the second section on [this page](http://www.steptools.com/support/stdev_docs/help/settings_vcnet.html) -- third screen shot.

Comment: Hi, I already had done this before. Is there a problem with the 64 bit OS that i am using as VS compiles for Win32. Also, which version of CUDA do i need: the 32 bit or the 64 bit.

Comment: OK. Then I think I know what's going on.  CUDA by default only installs 64 binaries.  I'm going to update my answer.  One sec.

Comment: I think we need to make it 64 somewhere  else also...any ideas?

Comment: How do you mean it 'skips the build'?  When you created an `x64` configuration, did you add the necessary projects to it as `x64 as well?

Comment: Not accepting your answer because i dont think it ws the source of the error. But i did give you a up arrow

Answer (score 2):

You should go to control panel then add/remove software. Then click on remove for Visual Studio and click next then you see "add or remove feature", click on it. Component 64x should be checked. I had same your problem before. By this way you can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest not to Add  headers, they gave me horrible linker errors. With Microsoft DLLS (msvrt and so on....)

I am not sure, but the  should not be in CUDA code, because its not supported

Can somebody confirm this?